# Illumination Normalization for Face Recognition

Tags: opencv, image-processing, normalization, pca, face-recognition

I am doing a project in Face Recognition. However, when I implemented the Illumination normalization I didn't get the expected results. 
I applied the ideal in the paper below:
http://lear.inrialpes.fr/pubs/2007/TT07/Tan-amfg07a.pdf

But the output images have different averages of grayscales, like this.
[image]

I am not sure but I guess it will significantly reduced the PCA-based face recognition rate. 
What I should do to get the similar averages of grayscales over images, like this.
[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want all the images have the same values of brightness/ grayscale as in the last row of the second figure. So what I could do to obtain it?

Comment: clearly there's a bug in your code. you should fix it.